# Question about encapsulation with example question

Tags: java, encapsulation

Question:

> Class SmartPhone, given below, violates the rule on encapsulation.
>   Re-write it so that encapsulation is preserved.

```
class Battery{
    private String type;
    private int voltage;
    public Battery(String t, int v){type = t; voltage = v}
    public String getType(){return type;}
    public int getVoltage(){return voltage;} 
    public void setType(String t){type = t;}
    public void setVoltage(int v){voltage = v;}
}

class SmartPhone {
    private Battery battery;
    private String make, model;
    public SmartPhone(String make, String model, Battery battery){
        this.make = make; this.model = model;
        this.battery = battery;
    }
    public String getMake(){return make;} 
    public String getModel(){return model;}

    //I think here it is breaking encapsulation
    public Battery getBattery(){return battery;}
}
```

I can not see any other rules breaking encapsulation, I can not rember why this is breaking it.

Is it because we are returning an instance of another class from outside that class in this example its`battery` hence breaking encapsulation?

Comment: *"violates the rule on encapsulation"* - I'm guessing this is from some study materials, which define a rule about encapsulation; please check those materials and find this rule, and edit it into the question.

Comment: I don't know what this rule is (you are probably told what it is), but my guess is that since `Battery` is mutable, you can mutate the phone's battery via the `Battery` object you got from `getBattery`. So to fix it, either make `Battery` immutable as well, or replace `getBattery` with `getBatteryType` and `getBatteryVoltage` that returns the properties of the battery. But this is only speculation...

Comment: Making `Battery` immutable is the sensible thing to do, but strictly speaking, the question asks you to re-write the `SmartPhone` class. That can be achieved by making defensive copies in the constructor and the getter (not optimal, since it returns an object with setters that the user might expect to be meaningful), or make the constructor take `batteryType` and `batteryVoltage` as parameters and replace `getBattery` with getters for those properties (which delegate to the `Battery`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a clearer definition of what you mean by "the rule on encapsulation", this question is a bit ambiguous. But I think the rule is probably [something like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming)#Information_hiding) (from Wikipedia):

> Under the definition that encapsulation "can be used to hide data members and member functions", the internal representation of an object is generally hidden from view outside of the object's definition. Typically, only the object's own methods can directly inspect or manipulate its fields. Hiding the internals of the object protects its integrity by preventing users from setting the internal data of the component into an invalid or inconsistent state.

By this rule, an object should be responsible for maintaining its own state, including the state of any other objects which are its components. It should not be possible for other code to change the state directly, without using the mutator methods the object makes available in its public interface.

Accordingly, the `SmartPhone` class violates encapsulation because it gives out access to its internal `battery` component, which has setter methods. If we consider the state of the battery to be part of the internal state of the phone (because the battery is a component of the phone), then the battery's setter methods allow mutation of that internal state, not via the phone's mutator methods.

There is more than one potential solution. My preferred option is to make the `Battery` class immutable:

```java
class Battery {
    private final String type;
    private final int voltage;
    public Battery(String t, int v) { type = t; voltage = v; }
    public String getType() { return type; }
    public int getVoltage() { return voltage; } 
}
```

This way, the `getBattery` method can freely return a reference to the internal `battery` component, safe from mutation by other code because the battery has no mutator methods.

However, the question sort of implies that the `SmartPhone` class is the one you are supposed to change, not the `Battery` class. Perhaps a battery is required to have setter methods for some other reason. In this case, the problem is a bit more subtle; the way your class is currently written, a reference to the internal `battery` object is available not just via the `getBattery` method, but also to whoever provided the battery when the object was constructed in the first place:

```java
> Battery b = new Battery("Lithium ion", 5);
> SmartPhone s = new SmartPhone("Banana", "bPhone 2", b);
> s.getBattery().getVoltage()
5 (int)
> b.setVoltage(240); // danger! high voltage!
> s.getBattery().getVoltage()
240 (int)
```

Note that we are able to mutate the battery without going via `s` at all, because we retain a reference `b` to the battery we supplied.

There are two ways around this, neither of which is as neat as making the battery immutable. The first way is to hide the internal details of the `Battery` class completely, and make it appear that the `SmartPhone` class just has all four properties itself:

```java
class SmartPhone {
    private final Battery battery;
    private final String make, model;

    public SmartPhone(String make, String model, String bType, int bVoltage) {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.battery = new Battery(bType, bVoltage);
    }

    public String getMake() { return make; } 
    public String getModel() { return model; }

    public String getBatteryType() { return battery.getType(); }
    public int getBatteryVoltage() { return battery.getVoltage(); }
}
```

This definitely doesn't allow outside access to the battery's mutator methods. Note that I've made the fields `final` since the class provides no way to change their values anyway.

Alternatively, we can make defensive copies to ensure that our private reference is never available to other code:

```java
class SmartPhone {
    private final Battery battery;
    private final String make, model;

    public SmartPhone(String make, String model, Battery battery) {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        // defensive copy
        this.battery = new Battery(battery.getType(), battery.getVoltage());
    }

    public String getMake() { return make; } 
    public String getModel() { return model; }

    public Battery getBattery() {
        // defensive copy
        return new Battery(battery.getType(), battery.getVoltage());
    }
}
```

I don't like this solution because it misleadingly makes it *appear* that the battery's mutator methods will do something useful, but these don't have the advertised effects:

```java
> Battery b = new Battery("Lithium ion", 5);
> SmartPhone s = new SmartPhone("Banana", "bPhone 2", b);
> b.setVoltage(240);
> s.getBattery().getVoltage()
5 (int)
> s.getBattery().setVoltage(240);
> s.getBattery().getVoltage()
5 (int)
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted, please leave a comment to explain why.

Comment: Encapsulation is about hiding implementation details---"preventing unauthorized parties' direct access to them" ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))). Making the Battery immutable does nothing by way of encapsulation because your getter still makes it visible to the outside world. See my answer.

Comment: According to the same Wikipedia page you cite, *"Under the definition that encapsulation "can be used to hide data members and member functions", the internal representation of an object is generally hidden from view outside of the object's definition. Typically, only the object's own methods can directly inspect or manipulate its fields. Hiding the internals of the object protects its integrity by preventing users from setting the internal data of the component into an invalid or inconsistent state."* This is the definition I am using.

Comment: Making `Battery` immutable preserves encapsulation because it prevents users from setting the internal data to an invalid or inconsistent state.

Comment: The benefit of encapsulation is that it lets you change implementation details later on. If you reveal the `Battery`, you cannot later swap in a different source of power, say a `SolarPanel`, because the outside world knows about batteries.

Comment: @ kaya3: Thanks I remember that is what the teacher said a `defensive copy` of the object perfect thanks for your detailed explanation

Comment: There are many benefits to encapsulation; the one I focused on is the preservation of validity of the object's internal state, as explained at the start of my answer. The reason I focused on this aspect is because I judged that this was the "rule" the question was referring to, and the question asks about that rule specifically rather than all aspects of encapsulation.

Comment: Whether or not a `Battery` is a value object is not a fact about the real world; it is a design decision which should be made depending on the purpose of the model. But I don't follow your objection at all. In the real world, of course you cannot sensibly take an existing battery and change its type or voltage; in the real world, those properties of a battery *are* fixed at the time the battery is manufactured. On the other hand, if the `Battery` class is supposed to represent information in a database about batteries, then updating those details makes sense. Those are design considerations.

Comment: And when you *use* the `Battery` its charge gradually reduces, right? It's not immutable. It changes state. It makes no sense to take a defensive copy because that's like magicking up a new battery out of nowhere.

Comment: And if this `Battery` class had a `charge` property, I would understand your objection; but it doesn't. The `Battery` class is probably not meant to model an individual battery, but rather a *kind* of battery that a *kind* of smartphone has. In that case, it wouldn't make sense to talk about the charge level of a kind of battery. As I said in my answer, I don't think the defensive copy is a good design, but in the narrow focus of the question (preserving the object's state against invalidation by outside mutation), it is a solution.

Comment: If you're talking about [anemic](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/AnemicDomainModel.html) data objects with no behavior then why bother with all this encapsulation. You're not writing object-oriented code in the first place.

Comment: Well, I'm sure we could both come up with more such criticisms of the design that this instructor has asked their students to work with, but that has no bearing on the question.

Answer (score -1):

Encapsulation means hiding the internal representation. Any methods that reveal the implementation (in particular `getBattery()`) need to be removed. I would start by removing all the getters.

```
class SmartPhone {
    private final Battery battery;
    private final String make, model;

    public SmartPhone(String make, String model, Battery battery){
        this.make = make; this.model = model;
        this.battery = battery;
    }
}
```

This encapsulates all the details of the implementation of the phone.

You should then add any methods representing *behaviors* that the phone should reveal, such as the ability to be turned on/off.

In my view, getters break encapsulation, but sometimes that's OK (like the `getMake()` and `getModel()` methods don't reveal much about the internals). You could provide a method that reveals the voltage, without revealing the details of the `Battery` object itself. This follows the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

```
class SmartPhone {
    private final Battery battery;
    private final String make, model;

    public SmartPhone(String make, String model, Battery battery){
        this.make = make; this.model = model;
        this.battery = battery;
    }

    public String getMake(){
        return make;
    } 

    public String getModel(){
        return model;
    }

    public int getVoltage() {
        return battery.getVoltage();
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Encapsulation is about hiding implementation details---*"preventing unauthorized parties' direct access to them"* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))).

**The accepted answer is wrong.** Making the Battery immutable does nothing by way of encapsulation because the getter still makes it visible to the outside world.

You need to remove the `getBattery()` method so that that implementation detail is hidden from users of the `SmartPhone`.

The benefit of encapsulation is that it lets you change implementation details later on. If you reveal the `Battery`, you cannot later swap in a different source of power, say a `SolarPanel` because the outside world knows about batteries.

Comment: I don't know how you are defining encapsulation, but all you seem to have done is changed the fields to `final`, removed the getter methods, and added a couple of new methods that are unrelated to the question as far as I can tell. This still violates encapsulation because the Battery's setter methods are available to whoever provides the `Battery` instance in the constructor or the `replaceBattery` method.